# Ruby on rails : How can i run/debug find bugs for ruby on rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did : git clone git@github.com:user/rails

Now how can i run/debug find bugs for ruby on rails 3.1 ?
Someone please mention the method completely.

Thanks.

Comment: What bugs do you want do debug/find in Ruby on Rails? Do you want to debug Ruby on Rails itself, or do you want to debug your RoR applications?

Comment: I am assuming @railshero wanted to participate in the rails 3.1 hackfest (more info here: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/7/14/rails-3-1-hackfest). This link also explains pretty good how to start or go about doing that. Where there any parts unclear for you?

Answer (score 2):

Add in your Gemfile :

```
gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Then in your console type :

```
bundle install
```

Then start your application with :

```
rails server --debugger
```

Then where ever you want to set up a break point, just write the word `debugger`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to contribute into the Rails core, first off you can use [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/113-contributing-to-rails-with-git), then read [official doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contribute.html).
Anyway it's not enough to do it. The best way is keep an eye on Rails chsngelog, test your projects and report about bugs, looking for potential bugs into Github Issues and trying to reproduce them localy. 
The value contributor is the man who care about code quality, stability and primarely spend spare time to help the community, help to real business projects.